# How to make use of KPixmapSequence on KDE Frameworks 5

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

On KDE4/Qt4 days KPixmapSequence("process-working", KIconLoader::SizeSmallMedium); would successfully load and show the process-working image, trying to port that to KDE Frameworks 5 that no longer works.

Any idea on how to make it work again? Does it have anything to do with Breeze theme using a SVG instead of PNG that Oxygen used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one needs KIconLoader to make it work:

```
auto seq = new KPixmapSequence;
seq->setSequence(
    KIconLoader::global()->loadPixmapSequence(
        QLatin1String("process-working"), KIconLoader::SizeSmallMedium));
```